# How to convert Microsoft word .docx header-sections to body text with python

Tags: python, python-docx

I recently generated some word documents from LimeSurvey and upon opening them, I was met with many unwanted header-sections that contain the text "Summary for {some_code}" but also page numbering.

I developed a short python script that removes both the header-sections and the footer:

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document('word1.docx')

for section in document.sections:
    # Remove footer and its page numbering
    footer = section.footer
    for paragraph in footer.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            run.text = ''
    
    # Remove header and disable "Link to Previous"
    header = section.header
    for paragraph in header.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            run.text = ''
    section.different_first_page_header_footer = False
    section.header.is_linked_to_previous = False

document.save('edited_doc.docx')
```

Unfortunately, LimeSurvey has mixed up the text i want to remove with some actual text that should be body text, but have been mixed up with the header-section text, and thus, my python script removes both the unwanted text and the actual text i want to keep.

So for this reason **I would like to convert all the header-sections to body text** so that i can remove the unwanted text and keep the one that was supposed to be there.

**How could i do it using python**?